# What Paypal SDK should I use?

Tags: asp.net, paypal

I'm working on an asp.net web application that has two types of users. Advertiser and Publisher. Both of them have credit(money) in their accounts.

I need to integrate Paypal payments so that an advertiser can add money to his balance. And also for the publisher to be able to withdraw money from his balance (money he made using the website).

I've gone through the Paypal REST and classic API's. Downloaded and browsed the .net code samples provided by Paypal themselves but I'm still having trouble deciding which SDK should I use to satisfy both scenarios with the best experience possible for the user. I'm inclined towards MassPay (in the MerchantSDK) for the withdrawals but I'm not 100% sure of this.

Any help or guidance is appreciated. 
Many thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  In general, we like questions asked here to have a concise, definite answer.  Unfortunately, questions regarding library / tool selection are explicitly off topic for the site, as they tend to be based more on opinion than on fact.

Comment: Oh hi there. I totally understand what you're stating here but allow me to differ respectfully that my question is not much a "help me choose a library" or a "which payment gateway should I use" kind of Q. It's just Paypal's documentation is so poor and confusing that I don't know what SDK to use to begin with and I need any guidance based on facts not mere opinions. Hope I've made my point clear. Thanks, mate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that you should use the REST SDKs if at all possible. PayPal's products are moving to that API and once everything is there, support for older SDKs will be discontinued.

Comment: I ended up using the MerchantSDK for now (more flexibility). I plan on migrating to the REST SDK when everything is totally there. Thanks, mate!